# Image mapping not working even following template

Tags: html, css, imagemap

Ive been reading some of the questions already asked on the site but i still cant seem to find any issues in my code. However, when i run the page, there is nothing clickable on my image.
Ive also compared it to the w3school.com code snippet on image mapping with the same results.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome!</title>
<style>
img     {display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;}
    
</style>
</head>

<body>

<img src="bodymap.jpg" style="width:50%" usemap="#body">

<map name="body">
    <area shape="rect" coords="233,828,485,994" alt="brain" href="brain.html">
</map>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You've forgotten to close the `<map` tag and open the `<html>` one. With these done and the image loaded, you should be good to go.

Comment: im sorry that was a pasting error on my behalf. The code i have open and the one i ran had the <map tag closed but ive now added the open html tag but it still doesnt work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears you have some spelling errors. Try the following:

```css
img     {
  display: block;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width:50%;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Welcome!</title>
  </head>

  <body>

    <img src="bodymap.jpg" usemap="#body">

    <map name="body">
      <area shape="rect" coords="233,828,485,994" alt="brain" href="brain.html">
    </map>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have incomplete closing tag `</map`, also no `<html>` tag,

This is your code:

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Welcome!</title>
<style>
img     {display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;}
    
</style>
</head>

<body>

<img src="bodymap.jpg" style="width:50%" usemap="#body">

<map name="body">
    <area shape="rect" coords="233,828,485,994" alt="brain" href="brain.html">
</map>

</body>

</html>
```

Try this example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
  <img src="https://www.imore.com/sites/imore.com/files/field/image/2015/03/mac-switch-thumbnail-padded_0.jpg" alt="Workplace" usemap="#workmap" width="400" height="400">
  <map name="workmap">
    <area shape="rect" coords="8,10,324,280" alt="Computer" href="https://www.google.com">
  </map>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

hi there is problem with your `coords` apart from spell mistakes..may be your cords are not proper check image size and `coords` over image there is nothing else wrong code is perfect there is problem with coords you put there.

try below coords:

```
<area shape="rect" coords="34,44,270,350" alt="Brain" href="brain.html">
```